# how to get fixed nav with full height section with content?

Tags: html, css

I am stuck here, i want to make fix nav with full height section with content but second section is not going good after scroll, need help.

Below my tried code:

```css
   *,
 *::after,
 *::before {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     box-sizing: inherit;
     -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
 }
 body,
 html {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 nav {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     background: tomato;
 }
 nav ul {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
 }
 nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 3px;
 }
 nav ul li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 5px;
     background: #000;
     color: #ddd;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 nav ul li a:hover {
     background: #ddd;
     color: #333;
 }
 section {
     height: 100vh;
     background: #303030;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 section p {
     margin-top: 54px;
     color: #fff;
 }
 section.green {
     background: green;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 section.green p {
     color: #ddd;
 }
```

```html
<section>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Service</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </section>
   <section class="green">
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </section>
</section>
```

Can anyone help me out and provide me a solution to my problem?

Comment: *"but second section is not going good after scroll, need help."* can you be a little more specific please? what's the problem and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: when you scroll the page the content goes inside the fix nav and you can see the space between both section, i want to fixed nav => after content sections with full of height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested `<section>` which is not recommended, a better approach should replace your outer `<section>` with `<div class="wrapper">...</div>`

Then use a `wrapper` class to set the `margin-top: 54px` which is the height of nav.

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 54px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #303030;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

For the overlap, use `calc` to set the height dynamically `height: calc(100vh - 52px);`

```css
*,
 *::after,
 *::before {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     box-sizing: inherit;
     -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
 }
 body,
 html {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 nav {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     background: tomato;
 }
 nav ul {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
 }
 nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 3px;
 }
 nav ul li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 5px;
     background: #000;
     color: #ddd;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 nav ul li a:hover {
     background: #ddd;
     color: #333;
 }
 section {
     height: 100vh;
     background: #303030;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 .wrapper {
     margin-top: 54px;
      height: 100vh;
     background: #303030;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 section p {
     color: #fff;
 }
 section.green {
     background: green;
     height: calc(100vh - 52px);
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 section.green p {
     color: #ddd;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Service</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </section>
   <section class="green">
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ! but green section content goes inside of nav you can see

Comment: @LokeshGupta what?

Comment: when you scroll the page green section content goes fixed nav bar how can i resolve it ?

Comment: @LokeshGupta I know your problem solved, but check my updated answer,  I suggest you not nest <section>, use a div with class wrapper will be better, for maintain and update =D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()` to calculate the height of the sections

---

```
height: calc(100vh - 54px); /*54px is the height of the nav*/
```

So this will make the height of each section have the height of the screen minus the height of the nav.

---

And to remove the space between the sections you need to remove `margin-top` from the `p` tag and add `padding-top:54px;`to the container, again `54px` is the height of the nav, and that for the sections to start right after the nav

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top:54px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background: tomato;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333;
}

section {
  height: calc(100vh - 54px);
  background: #303030;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
}

section p {
  
  color: #fff;
}

section.green {
  background: green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

section.green p {
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</section>
<section class="green">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man but as you can see the space between grey and green section, how can i fix it

Comment: Thanks buddy it's work can you explain how this resolved ?

Comment: @LokeshGupta i added some explaination in my answer.. see edit!